# Add message saying "Question was deleted" instead of the generic Page Not Found

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, deleted-questions, 404-not-found

Yesterday I have posted an answer to the question [How to get parent id of a root node from front end to insert a child node into list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303934/how-to-get-parent-id-of-a-root-node-from-front-end-to-insert-a-child-node-into-li), and the OP posted some comments that got into my inbox:

[image: screenshot]

However, when now browsing to the question, I'm getting Page Not Found which I believe means the OP or someone else deleted the message for some reason.

In my opinion, it's better to show "Question has been deleted [by ...]" instead, at least for one day or for members who were "active" in the question otherwise it's pretty confusing.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Based on additional feedback, I elected to implement this in a better way.

When viewing a 404 page:

#### If the question was deleted by somebody else, and *you* are the author

> Your question was removed from Stack Overflow for reasons of moderation. Please refer to [the FAQ](/faq#deletion) for possible reasons why your question might have been removed.

#### If the question was deleted by somebody else, and you are *not* the author

> This question was removed from Stack Overflow for reasons of moderation. Please refer to [the FAQ](/faq#deletion) for possible reasons why a question might be removed.

#### If the question was deleted by its author, and *you* are the author

> This question was voluntarily removed by its author – *that's you!*

#### If the question was deleted by its author, and you are *not* the author

> This question was voluntarily removed by its author.

This text appears at the top of the page with revision highlights on the relevant bits of text. The rest of the 404 page was not changed (for the purposes of this answer, I did clean up some display issues).

Comment: Thanks Jeff that's exactly what I asked for - and I love the yellow highlight! Guess now less people will come here wondering "what happened to this question". :)

Comment: It seems just slightly redundant to still have "We couldn't find the page you requested." You could find it; you found it; it had been deleted; you told us so. I definitely like that it now says when a question has been deleted, but on those 404 pages, don't you think saying that it couldn't be found is a bit... incorrect?

Comment: @nhinkle - it's technically correct from the browser point of view. The page status is still 404 as far as I can tell.

Comment: @shadow It would be more technically correct to say, `550 Permission Denied` since the post exists, but the user does not have rights (ie, 10k rep and signed in) to view it.  However, that would likely result in a slew of support inquiries regarding whether one is logged in correctly since so few people are used to and comfortable with the variety of HTTP status codes that exist - save for 404, page not found.  I'd prefer a permission denied, but I can understand why a company might choose instead to placate the user with a simpler, though incorrect, message.

Comment: @Adam good point, but probably 404 is for the best for the reasons you said. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard the browser is not parsing the HTML on the page, seeing "we couldn't find the page you requested", and interpreting it as a 404. It's seeing the HTTP header and determines based on that. The status code sent is correct from a browser point of view; the text on the page is incorrect from a _human_ point of view.

Comment: @nhinkle I think you are massively overthinking this, personally.. :p

Comment: And @nhinkle, have you been suffering the IE [so-called friendly HTTP error messages](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/08/19/http-error-pages-in-internet-explorer.aspx)? ;-)

Comment: @Arjan Me? Use IE? Pshaw. No, I've been seeing the correct page. It's just a minor quibble.

Comment: @nhinkle: since we are nitpicking 404 is not the correct status for deleted questions, it should be 410 Gone

Comment: Yes, 410 looks like a better status code here.

Comment: @Koper, a bit late, but see [Deleted questions should return 410 Gone instead of 404 Not Found](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125176/deleted-questions-should-return-410-gone-instead-of-404-not-found) as for why (apparently) 404 is better than 410.