# Don't show "removed from [site name] for reasons of moderation" for self-deleted posts

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, deleted-questions, wording, self-delete

I just deleted a post on the DBA SE beta site. When I tried to return to that page, I got the following message:

> ### Page Not Found
>
> Your question was `removed from Database Administrators - Stack Exchange for reasons of moderation`. Please refer to [**the FAQ**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion) for possible explanations why your question might have been removed.

The system shouldn't show the "hey, we had to bring a mod in to clean up your mess, loser" text for self-deletes.

Comment: I just did this here on meta and got no such message. Does this only happen if you have < 10K? (and if so - what's *that* like?)

Comment: I just reproed on both SU and Board and Card Games. @status, can you log out or open a different browser and try it as a non-10ker?

Comment: When I view after logging off I get the normal 404. I don't have an account with less than 10K, so I can't try otherwise. Since you've got < 10K on the sites where you did this, I think that's the trick. It kinda makes sense, as a 10K shouldn't need that message. And, of course, it's not needed on self-deleted posts.

Comment: @status, what I meant was to post and delete a question as an unregistered user; that's a <10k account anyone can access.

Comment: @Pop - I did (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758990/test-question-i-will-delete-this), but I can't delete it. Ugh.

Comment: Now I feel dirty inside :(

Comment: Based on the wording of the message, my guess is that the OP is *the only one that actually sees this message.*

Comment: Ah, here are the rules for the wording: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71179/add-message-saying-question-was-deleted-instead-of-the-generic-page-not-found/85858#85858.

Comment: @Robert - there's no case for the owner viewing his/her own self-deleted question.

Comment: @status: True enough.

Comment: @status The first case shown there includes self-deletion. My revision changed it to specify that the only thing that matters in that case is that you're the owner, regardless of who actually deleted it.

Comment: Regardless, I'd consider that this _is_ a bug, albeit low priority.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is an insane thing to even bring up, but whatever. Easy fix, so...

> This question was voluntarily removed by its author – *that's you!*

Comment: I think it was insane to ever write "for reasons of moderation" in that case, but whatever - I'm happy that it's fixed!