# When visiting your own self-deleted questions without 10k reputation, you get "removed for reasons of moderation" instead of "voluntarily removed"

Tags: bug, deleted-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Don't show “removed from [site name] for reasons of moderation” for self-deleted posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88493/dont-show-removed-from-site-name-for-reasons-of-moderation-for-self-deleted)

I posted [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89516/deleted-answers-are-no-longer-shown-to-their-owners-why), then deleted it.

What I see:

> Your question was removed from Meta Stack Overflow for reasons of moderation. Please refer to the FAQ for possible explanations why your question might have been removed.

What I see when logged out:

> This question was voluntarily removed by its author.

Comment: I see "This question was voluntarily removed by its author." while logged in.

Comment: @Wes: Because you're not the author. (It's the same badp it seeing when logged out!)