# Deleted question page says question was moderated, but it was self-deleted

Tags: bug, deleted-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Don't show "removed from [site name] for reasons of moderation" for self-deleted posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88493/dont-show-removed-from-site-name-for-reasons-of-moderation-for-self-deleted)

I was whining about how self-deleted questions described themselves improperly, when [Dr. Mrozek corrected me](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102274/how-can-we-find-out-the-reasons-for-an-area-51-discussion-being-deleted#comment-260729).  However, I've reproduced the behavior — at the expense of preventing his answer to my deleted question from getting any rep, oops.  Your sacrifice is acknowledged.

Anyways, it should say it was voluntarily removed by the author, and it does if I'm not logged in.  But when I *am* logged in, I see the reason-of-moderation message:

[image: screenshot]

Theoretically, it *would* also be moderation if I deleted my own question on Android or Music, but not here on MSO.  So this looks to be a bug.  If intended, I don't get it ... why hide from the user that they deleted their post? They already know, and the workaround to see the real reason is dead simple.

Comment: Duplicates: [Don't show “removed from \[site name\] for reasons of moderation” for self-deleted posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/88493), [When visiting your own self-deleted questions without 10k reputation, you get "removed for reasons of moderation" instead of "voluntarily removed" \[closed\]](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89518)

Comment: Thanks, that lead me to the rules which I have railed against.

Comment: SWEET it was fixed! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71179/add-message-saying-question-was-deleted-instead-of-the-generic-page-not-found/85858#85858