# Is there a way to auto-identify tag synonyms which differ by *only* a hyphen?

Tags: discussion, tags, data-explorer, search

Note: There is a nice background discussion on this here: [Should tags take the form foobar or foo-bar?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2813/152009).  This discussion is not part of this question however:

---

I'd like to go through and propose a bunch of synonyms for tags as either [filepath](/questions/tagged/filepath) -> [file-path](/questions/tagged/file-path) or [file-path](/questions/tagged/file-path) -> [filepath](/questions/tagged/filepath).

**My Question:** Is there a way through the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) or [Advanced Search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=) or [tag page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) to identify the tags which **only differ by a hyphen**?

Comment: why don't we disallow creation of new tags that differ from existing by hyphen only ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's pretty easy with SEDE; there's an alarming [607 results](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/109920/find-tags-that-only-differ-by-hyphenation)

```sql
SELECT a.TagName AS First, b.TagName AS Second
FROM Tags AS a, Tags AS b
WHERE a.Id < b.Id
AND REPLACE(a.TagName, '-', '') = REPLACE(b.TagName, '-', '');​
```

Comment: @MTibbits I've been [demoted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102300/deleted-question-page-says-question-was-moderated-but-it-was-self-deleted) :(

Comment: Ps.  Sorry 'bout that!

Answer (score 8):

I just added some rules to stop us from bleeding in future.

[image: bacon]

If you attempt to create the tag `bac-on` and the tag `bacon` already exists we will block you. Same goes for the reverse.