# Calling all synonymists! We need your help! And now plural(s) too?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, clean-up

There is a straightforward query [provided by Michael Mrozek](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103163/is-there-a-way-to-auto-identify-tag-synonyms-which-differ-by-only-a-hyphen/103165#103165) with SEDE

## Alarming Results

There are [607 tag pairs on Stack Overflow](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/109920/find-tags-that-only-differ-by-hyphenation) which differ by only a hyphen!!

```sql
SELECT a.TagName AS First, b.TagName AS Second
FROM Tags AS a, Tags AS b
WHERE a.Id < b.Id
AND REPLACE(a.TagName, '-', '') = REPLACE(b.TagName, '-', '');​
```

---

## Call to Arms

After [upvoting his awesomeness](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103163/is-there-a-way-to-auto-identify-tag-synonyms-which-differ-by-only-a-hyphen/103165#103165), please make synonym suggestions.  Note that this data is a month old, so -- for example -- [stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow) and [stack-overflow](/questions/tagged/stack-overflow) were already proposed, **but still need votes!!**

And, lest you think this is on a problem on Stack Overflow, [Programmers has six tag pairs](https://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/q/109920/find-tags-that-only-differ-by-hyphenation) and I'm sure there are plenty others out there -- Super User has 29.  Server Fault has 55.  Let's get those [badges](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/150/synonymizer)!

## And also Plurals

After learning a bit more SQL, I've also constructed a query for tags which differ by only ending in 's' or 'es'.  [**There are currently 614 tag pairs on Stack Overflow which fit this criterion.**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/110005/find-tags-that-only-differ-by-plurality)  Now it does incorrectly catch ([css](/questions/tagged/css), [c](/questions/tagged/c)) as well as  ([aes](/questions/tagged/aes), [a](/questions/tagged/a)), but it certainly has plenty of synonyms to suggest!!

- [112 on Server Fault](https://data.stackexchange.com/serverfault/q/110005/find-tags-that-only-differ-by-plurality)
- [37 on Super User](https://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/q/110005/find-tags-that-only-differ-by-plurality)
- [28 on Programmers](https://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/q/109997/find-tags-that-only-differ-by-plurality)

Comment: Only if the [tag synonym main page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms) contained those vote buttons so that I don't need to click a zillion of times to vote every individual synonym..

Comment: @Chichiray See [synonym suggestions](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1748/synonym-suggestions). If only the query results could add links to those records...

Comment: Somebody kick Operation Chaos...

Comment: Speaking of synonyms. . .Perhaps [meta-tag:call-to-arms] could be a synonym for [meta-tag:posse], or vice versa?

Comment: I liked [tag:call-to-arms], but either way works for me.  ;O)

Comment: Here is a link to see all synonym suggestions (on Stack Overflow) where you are allowed to vote: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested. (This includes those where you already have voted, though.)

Comment: Wow...wish I had the rep to help.

Comment: @John, Please [see this feature-request to allow more of us *able* to help](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/103211)

Comment: Change the vote threshold then. I stopped suggesting synonyms because nothing ever happened... why waste my time?

Answer (score 3):

Among the many proposals generated by these queries, here's a three -> one:

- [performance-counter](/questions/tagged/performance-counter) (6 questions) -> [performance-counters](/questions/tagged/performance-counters)
- [performancecounters](/questions/tagged/performancecounters) (3 questions)  -> [performance-counters](/questions/tagged/performance-counters)
- [performancecounter](/questions/tagged/performancecounter) (191 questions)  -> [performance-counters](/questions/tagged/performance-counters)

though [performance-counters](/questions/tagged/performance-counters) only has 33 questions, the:

- phrase is two words, meriting the hyphen
- plurals *tend* to be preferred as 'all-encompassing'

And the same goes for:

- [control-templates](/questions/tagged/control-templates) (2 questions) -> [control-templates](/questions/tagged/control-templates)
- [controltemplates](/questions/tagged/controltemplates) (19 questions)  -> [control-templates](/questions/tagged/control-templates)
- [controltemplate](/questions/tagged/controltemplate) (302 questions) -> [control-templates](/questions/tagged/control-templates)

though [control-templates](/questions/tagged/control-templates) only has 2 questions.  So perhaps [controltemplate](/questions/tagged/controltemplate) instead?

**Update:** And for...

- [web-controls](/questions/tagged/web-controls) (31 questions) -> [web-controls](/questions/tagged/web-controls)
- [webcontrols](/questions/tagged/webcontrols) (189 questions)  -> [web-controls](/questions/tagged/web-controls)
- [webcontrol](/questions/tagged/webcontrol) (58 questions) -> [web-controls](/questions/tagged/web-controls)

though [control-templates](/questions/tagged/control-templates) only has 31 questions?

Comment: I'd love to see if `customcomponents`, `customcomponent` and `custom-component` could all get merged/synonymized to a new tag `custom-components`.

Answer (score 2):

See also these queries:

- https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/433/tags-spelling-variants-dashes
- https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/432/tags-spelling-variants-singular-plural
- https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/431/tags-spelling-variants-ae-be-z-s