# How can I tell at a glance which synonyms I can vote on?

Tags: support, voting, tag-synonyms

Inspired by the brave efforts in [Calling all synonymists! We need your help! And now plural(s) too?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103168/calling-all-synonymists-we-need-your-help) I went to check out the voting on synonyms.

I'm eligible with respect to reputation, and I'm certain I'm eligible to vote on some synonyms, but there seems to be no way to tell which ones without going back and forth between my profile and the synonyms screen (or attempting to vote on each of them and getting the rejection notice).

Is there a quicker way to tell at a glance on which synonyms I can vote?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you hit the `Suggested` tab, it will only show you tags that you can vote on.

Note that the only way to know if you have voted on them is to actually hit the leftmost tag in a row, and then see if you've already voted on the suggestions there.