# View all tag synonyms I can vote on

Tags: support, tag-synonyms, data-explorer

Is there any way to view all tag synonyms that I can vote on, with my tag scores?

I can't find anything in the main interface, but perhaps there's a data query I can't find?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can. In `http://X.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested&tab=newest` you can see the pending suggestions from others peers that you can vote on. You can vote synonym of any tag that you have score +5, so just visiting your profile and ordering by score should be enough.

Comment: This page comes up blank on all the sites I tried - I'm pretty sure there ARE suggested synonyms on SO! Am I missing something?

Comment: Aha - wait, my answer's here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/103183/233816 - It appears there's nothing I can vote on. Also looks like, despite all my searching, this is a duplicate question...