# Do we need to clean up all the duplicate cross site tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, site-recommendation, migration, burninate-request

I'm seeing lots of duplicate tags across stacks:

- Stack Overflow's [inkscape](/questions/tagged/inkscape) tag
- Stack Overflow's [gimp](/questions/tagged/gimp) tag
- Ask Ubuntu's [gimp](/questions/tagged/gimp) tag
- Ask Ubuntu's [inkscape](/questions/tagged/inkscape) tag
- Ask Ubuntu's [photoshop](/questions/tagged/photoshop) tag
- Super User's [gimp](/questions/tagged/gimp) tag
- Super User's [inkscape](/questions/tagged/inkscape) tag
- Super User's [adobe-photoshop](/questions/tagged/adobe-photoshop) tag
- Graphic Design's [gimp](/questions/tagged/gimp) tag
- Graphic Design's [inkscape](/questions/tagged/inkscape) tag
- Graphic Design's [adobe-photoshop](/questions/tagged/adobe-photoshop) tag

Those are only a few of the duplicate tags everywhere. I'm sure we can find them on more sites in the Stack Exchange network.

So, do we leave them as they are of all migrate them to Graphic Design?

If we migrate them, we should also blacklist those tags.

Comment: I can't comment on SO's case, but "biochemistry" is an awesome tag, both for chem.SE and bio.SE. The premise that 'any cross site tag has been mistakenly created.' or anything suchlike is flawed.

Comment: Plus for example a gimp installation issue might be best on Ask Ubuntu, whereas a usage question would fit on Graphic Design and a question about writing a plugin on Stack Overflow.

Comment: What about "table"? Must mean the same on dba.se and diy.se..., eh? And even if they did mean the same, what problem is having the same tag name in different sites?

Answer (score 12):

Leave them where they are. It is nice there is a [gimp](/questions/tagged/gimp) tag on Graphics, but so can there be one on Stack Overflow if its questions are related to programming a plugin for example. No way that question is on-topic on Graphics.

Tags with the same name across the network is no issue at all.

Where would all [apple](/questions/tagged/apple) questions go? Biology or Ask Different? :)

Answer (score 4):

Another point that should be mentioned is that duplicate tags help facilitate migrations across sites. From the [migration faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10249/214632)

> A migration can be automatically rejected before it even gets migrated if any of the following conditions apply: ...
>
> - The question does not contain any tags that exist on the destination site (and the destination site isn't a meta site)

A strict "no duplicate tags" requirement across SE would make it much more difficult to move off-topic questions to where they belong (without [discarding this check](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210532) which is so far [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)).