# Why this question shows removed "for reasons of moderation" rather than "voluntarily removed by its author"?

Tags: bug, deleted-questions, self-delete

The post [Don't show “removed from [site name] for reasons of moderation” for self-deleted posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/88493) is marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) and if I understand it correctly, if a question was self-deleted then users without privilege to see deleted posts should get the message "This question was voluntarily removed by its author."

On Mathematics Stack Exchange, there was recently this question: [Given $N$ integers on a circle , what will be the minimum pair sum?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3283956) I am shown information that it was "deleted by user668959" and I see the same information in the [revision history](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3283956/revisions) and [timeline](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3283956/timeline). Yet when I display the same question while not logged in, I get "This question was removed from Mathematics Stack Exchange for reasons of moderation." (I am also shown that the question had one close vote - I am not sure whether this could influence the result.) For users who cannot view this question here is a screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

Here is what I get while not logged in:

[image: screenshot in incognito mode]

I'll add that the discrepancy was pointed out to me in comments on this Meta MathOverflow discussions: [Rules for deleting one's own question](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/4292).

I have tried to check one self-deleted question [of my own](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3183992/test-of-a-tag-warning) and one [by another user](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30394/how-can-we-export-a-post-including-the-question-answers-and-comments). On those questions I got the message "voluntarily removed by its author" when viewing them while not logged in.

Comment: the user is disassociated/deleted, so that might simply break the check whether the owner is the user that deleted the post.

Comment: Ironically, the screenshot you decided to show was one that *doesn't* give the "reasons of moderation" message.

Comment: @JasonBassford Well, if you insist. I thought that the first screenshot would be more useful; since not every user can view deleted questions. (Everybody can check the message displayed simply by clicking the link - if needed by switching to incognito mode/private browsing.)

Comment: @Martin That's much better. Posts should be self-contained and give you all the information (and examples) you need without relying on having you click to an external source. With the additional screenshot and information, the question now makes immediate sense.

Comment: @MadScientist It does break the check; see the proposed duplicate.