# I cannot edit the post

Tags: discussion, edits

Why can't I edit the question [Problem in removing and showing row in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5829076/problem-in-removing-and-showing-row-in-jquery)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's been deleted while you were editing it. If you follow that link you'll see:

> This question was voluntarily removed by its author.

Comment: You mean, he will see 404 page not found error?

Comment: @YOU: The 404 error page now contains some additional information explaining how the question got deleted. Something like "voluntarily removed by its author" or "removed for reasons of moderation".

Comment: @Cody, wow, really!, great to know that.

Comment: @YOU: See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71179/add-message-saying-question-was-deleted-instead-of-the-generic-page-not-found Sometimes it's hard to keep up with these things; past 10k, you don't get many 404s.