# Don't remove deleted questions from owner's view and let them see them regardless of reputation

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted)

As it is, one needs 10k reputation to see deleted posts made by everyone else. But there is no reputation limit to see your own deleted answers ([self-deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621432/t-sql-how-create-list-as-comma-separated-string-in-one-select/7621441#7621441) or [otherwise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621330/multiple-static-variable-scopes-within-same-application/7621350#7621350)). Not only that, but answers deleted by someone else have a link to the FAQ:

[image]
**Questions** on the other hand will vanish without a trace for anyone with less than 10k. They'll be redirected to a 404 page, leaving users with [little clue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71179/add-message-saying-question-was-deleted-instead-of-the-generic-page-not-found/85858#85858) as to what happened. They also get no notifications of any kind.

I tested this by setting up a [new account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/971470/dfish) and asking a [bad question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621150/please-fix-this-piece-of-code). Unfortunately it wasn't bad enough and it was taking a while for it to get deleted, so I asked a [worse question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621272/), which got promptly deleted. There are no notifications, no messages, *nada* - it just vanishes.

Now that 20ks can delete bad questions immediately, It would help to allow anyone to see a list of their deleted questions (ie: along with non-deleted questions) *and* access the deleted questions themselves. The comments and the close reason should help everyone but the most clueless to figure out what's the problem(s) with their question and hopefully prevent them from making the same mistake(s) in the future.

**NOTE:** All links are 10k only.

Comment: As an aside: there is *some* clue, [like](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71179/add-message-saying-question-was-deleted-instead-of-the-generic-page-not-found/85858#85858): "[...] for reasons of moderation".

Comment: @Arjan Most people won't pay much attention to the text in 404s. They'll just see it's an error and give up.

Comment: True, also: the 404 is only shown when one still knows the URL, like when bookmarked or when using some outdated search engine.

Comment: Haha, [someone screwed your japanese question up](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/7621272/2). Rollbacked by me

Comment: Also see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/951/can-we-get-a-list-of-our-content-thats-been-deleted which

Comment: So you're only asking to show the content to authors who look at their own, deleted question, when they know the URL. Right? Or do you also want those deleted questions *listed* somewhere in one's own profile? (Deleted answers are not listed in one's own profile either.)

Comment: @Arjan Both. Jeff says why he's against this [here.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted/53297#53297), but I think recent changes to SO invalidate his concerns.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionஇ_இ his _real_ reason appears to be in a comment -- "it would lead to unbelievable amounts of whining. Will not get implemented as long as I am still alive to prevent it from happening." Unfortunately, I don't think any changes to SO can invalidate that, so this request might have more traction if restricted to some reputation level, with 10k+ being the obvious one.

Comment: @agf That defeats the purpose of this request. I think low rep users to see *why* their questions were deleted.