# Can you add cache link to Page not found?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, 404-not-found

Given Fabian's answer and its comments, **on second thoughts I don't think the following is a good idea.**

---

When you have a page not found such as on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999999999999999999/:D) or you have a question that [has been removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150043/python-v-perl). I think it would be a good idea to put a link leading to Google's (or some other crawler's cache) cache.

Maybe something like this (sorry for my bad mspainting):
[image: mockup]

Note my added "Get Google's cache". It could be something else though.

Comment: the cache links expire too.

Comment: @Sathya maybe only do it for when it isn't expired

Comment: (+1 for *not* wanting this anymore.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Users with more than 10k reputation can already see deleted posts. There is no need to rely on any cache from a third-party, SE only soft-deletes content in most cases.

That non-10k users cannot see these posts is by design, so it's unlikely that they implement some way around it. The question you show in your screenshot was deleted by moderators or high-reputation users because it was a bad fit for SO. There is no reason to keep it visible, it's hidden for most users intentionally.

Comment: I picked that question because I was reading a post on the se blog that featured it

Comment: But, @Anish, how would this be any different for other deleted questions? Whether [voluntarily deleted by its author or deleted by the community or moderators](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71179/add-message-saying-question-was-deleted-instead-of-the-generic-page-not-found/85858#85858): we wanted the post gone. Linking to some cache makes no sense to me at all.

Comment: @Arjan maybe sometimes something goes wrong in the se servers. There's a proper question that se seems to have lost

Comment: @AnishGupta When it says "removed from Stack Overflow for reasons of moderation" the question was intentionally removed by moderators. We don't want those questions to hang around, they were deleted for a reason.

Comment: If something goes wrong, @Anish, I think we better link to Meta to file a new bug report...

Comment: Answerer and @Arjan I understand completely about reasons for moderation and voluntarily removed by author. I have changed my mind about that. But as I said in my previous comment what if the se servers get it wrong

Comment: @Arjan I cant seem to find a lot of questions. Maybe that's because maintenance is happening now

Comment: @AnishGupta - Why should Fabian destroy perfectly valid content so you can delete your question?